# How to print a certain category in inheritance using instanceof function?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, instanceof

My three subclasses are talkshow, song, and commercial for the radio class. I only have talk show shown here. When I, for example, enter s, p, or m for the subcategory. It prints everything for that subclass when I only want one subcategory to be printed.

The sample data will be below.

```
1000,S,The Newest Star,Space,51:20,T2.mp3
1001,P,Interview With George,Politics,15:00,george.mp3
1002,P,Crooks in Politics,Politics,21:35,crooks.mp3
1010,M,Cooking For Vegetarians,Food,5:00,vege2.mp3
1222,S,Where Is The Sun,Larries,23:33,larscience.mp3
```

But if I choose "P" for sub category for talk show it should only print these two as shown below.

```
1001,P,Interview With George,Politics,15:00,george.mp3
1002,P,Crooks in Politics,Politics,21:35,crooks.mp3
```

This is the part of my code

```
private void searchCategoryToPrint() 
    {
        String inputCategory = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose from Radio Categories: Talk Show, Song, or Commercial\n" +
                                                           "and enter the chosen category");
        String subCategory = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Talk Show: S Science, P Politics, and M Miscellaneous\n");
        if("talk show".equalsIgnoreCase(inputCategory))
        {
                for(Radio radioShows : radioList)
                {
                    if("SPM".contains(subCategory.toUpperCase().substring(0)) && radioShows instanceof TalkShow)
                    {
                        System.out.println(radioShows.formatForFile());
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: what's your code for `Radio`? what are its fields? is there some way to get the subcategory from it? Then, you should change your `if` to compare `subCategory` with `radioShows.getSubcategory()` or whatever you have.

Comment: I tried to do that by using the category. Although these are my fields for the radio class, and it is for radio. Yes. Fields: id, category, title, host, playtime, and audiofile.

Comment: I would break the if ("SPM"....) in two if() until I got it right. Reverse the string comparison and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `if` condition to check if the radio show has the same sub category as the one selected from your dialog:

```
if(radioShows.getCategory().equalsIgnoreCase(subCategory.substring(0)) && radioShows instanceof TalkShow) {
    System.out.println(radioShows.formatForFile());
}
```